# what is epsilon/k how did that come in epsilon greedy algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

As it was told it would choose the arm having highest emperical mean with probability 1-epsilon how did epsilon/k add to it (and also epsilon/k for random probability selection)in the equation written for probability in the page no:6 of the paper[Algorithms for multi armed bandits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.6028.pdf).What does that mean epsilon/k writing there in the equation

Comment: General questions about machine learning should be posted to their specific communities.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was taken from [here](https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2017/11/30/the-epsilon-greedy-algorithm/):

Suppose you are standing in front of k = 3 slot machines. Each machine pays out according to a different probability distribution, and these distributions are unknown to you. And suppose you can play a total of 100 times.

You have two goals. The first goal is to experiment with a few coins to try and determine which machine pays out the best. The second, related, goal is to get as much money as possible. The terms “explore” and “exploit” are used to indicate that you have to use some coins to explore to find the best machine, and you want to use as many coins as possible on the best machine to exploit your knowledge.

Epsilon-greedy is almost too simple. As you play the machines, you keep track of the average payout of each machine. Then, you select the machine with the highest current average payout with probability = (1 – epsilon) + (epsilon / k) where epsilon is a small value like 0.10. And you select machines that don’t have the highest current payout average with probability = epsilon / k.
It much easier to understand with a concrete example. Suppose, after your first 12 pulls, you played machine #1 four times and won $1 two times and $0 two times. The average for machine #1 is $2/4 = $0.50.

And suppose you’ve played machine #2 five times and won $1 three times and $0 two times. The average payout for machine #2 is $3/5 = $0.60.

And suppose you’ve played machine #3 three times and won $1 one time and $0 two times. The average payout for machine #3 is $1/3 = $0.33.

Now you have to select a machine to play on try number 13. You generate a random number p, between 0.0 and 1.0. Suppose you have set epsilon = 0.10. If p > 0.10 (which it will be 90% of the time), you select machine #2 because it has the current highest average payout. But if p < 0.10 (which it will be only 10% of the time), you select a random machine, so each machine has a 1/3 chance of being selected.

Notice that machine #2 might get picked anyway because you select randomly from all machines.

Over time, the best machine will be played more and more often because it will pay out more often. In short, epsilon-greedy means pick the current best option ("greedy") most of the time, but pick a random option with a small (epsilon) probability sometimes.

There are many other algorithms for the multi-armed bandit problem. But epsilon-greedy is incredibly simple, and often works as well as, or even better than, more sophisticated algorithms such as UCB ("upper confidence bound") variations.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try giving my point of view here.
Lets consider the similar example of 3 machines: A, B and C and assume B has the highest pay out.

If epsilon is 0.1, then what is the probability of choosing B?

Recall Epsilon Greedy algo, it says:

```
 r = random() # any random number between 0 and 1(uniform distribution)
 if r > epsilon:
    choose "Best pay out at current time" #(currently it is B)
 else:
    choose randomly between three machines
```

so what is the probable number of chances of choosing B in 100 chances:
It will be sum of the below two:
1) 90 chances out of 100 (if condition)
2) one third chances out of remaining 10(else condition) as there are 3 machines(equal possibility of choosing each of them)

So the total chances can be 90 + 10* (1/3) (approx) = 93.33

But wait what if epsilon is 0.5?
Then total chances would be 95 + 5*(1/3)= 96.67

Thats y we say, probability of selecting the machine with the highest current average payout with probability = (1 – epsilon) + (epsilon / k).

I hope this helps.